# Why is the normal vector $\nu= \frac{y-x}{r} $ for a unit ball in the divergence theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, partial-differential-equations

In Evan's textbook(Mean-value formulas for Laplace's equation) If $u\in C^2(U)$ is harmonic, then $$u(x)=\bar{\int} udS$$
where $\bar{\int}$ is the average integral.

Why
$$\bar{\int}_{\partial B(x,r)} Du(y)\frac{y-x}{r} dS(y)\\
=\bar{\int}_{\partial B(x,r)} \frac{\partial u}{\partial\nu} dS(y)\\=\frac{r}{n}\bar{\int}_{ B(x,r)} \Delta u(y)dy$$

where $Du\cdot \nu=\frac{\partial u}{\partial\nu}$ and by the divergence theorem.

> But why the normal vector $\nu$ is the $\frac{y-x}{r} $ in the divergence theorem?

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12561/how-to-type-average-integral

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A diagram will help.

[image]

It is 2D but for any point in a ball exists a section like this. Consider too that $\left|y-x\right|=r$.

Comment: But how to understand it by formula?

Comment: Or how to get the normal vector for a ball $B(0, r)$?

Comment: $y$ is the positon vector for a generic point in the ball and $x$ is the one for its center. It is known that $y-x$ lies between the segment defined by these points, thus, it corresponds to a radius of the ball ( and pointing outwards). We have $\nu=(y-x)/|y-x|=(y-x)/r$ a unitary vector prallel to the radius, so orthogonal to the ball's border $\partial B$

Comment: @RafaBudría Why the vector $\frac{\lvert y-x \rvert}{r}$ have as point of application the boundary of the ball?

Comment: @NatMath, there are two vectors calculated for each point of the ball and we use their dot product (at that point) into the surface integral. Each of vectors used lie in the tangent space of each point, not exactly a point of application.

Comment: @RafaBudríaSo, if we write the surface in Cartesian coordinates, that is, $F(z_1,\dots,z_n)=(z_1-x_1)^2+\cdots +(z_n-x_n)^2-r^2=0$ then the vector is given by the gradient of this function on the norm of the gradient, right?

Comment: @NatMath, Yes. There are several ways to compute that vector. I choose a more classical one considering the symmetry of the integral.